# regular expression match domain

Tags: regex, pcre

I need a regular expression to match the following domains as follows:

```
http://www.cnn.com/fred      = www.cnn.com
cnn.com                      = cnn.com
www.cnn.com:8080             = www.cnn.com
```

I have the following regular expression (using pcre):

```
([^/]+://)?([^:/]+)
```

The above works fine in case 2 and 3 however with 1 i still have the http:// appended to the matching string, is there a regular expression option which i can use to skip the http part?

many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this looks like the closest i could get to what i want not perfect but seems to gets the job done

```
www?([^/:]+)
```

Answer (score 1):

This one should suit your needs:

```
^(?:(?:f|ht)tps?://)?([^/:]+)
```

The first group will contain what you're looking for.

Comment: hi there, i tried this on http://www.regextester.com it still gives me a match with http:// appended at the front